# C# TimeSpan.Milliseconds formated to 2 digits

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, timespan

I have a timer that I want to show `minutes:seconds:hundreds of seconds`.
Since C# timespan doesn't have a method to get hundreds but only milliseconds, I need to somehow format this.

```
TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
currentTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(ts.Milliseconds),2));
ClockTextBlock.Text = currentTime;
```

I've tried with `Math.Round` and nothing happened. The result is still anywhere from 1-3 digit, like this:

```
01:12:7
01:12:77
01:12:777
```

I want format to always be like

```
01:12:07
01:12:77
```

Comment: You can also use a DateTime object for the start time and a DateTime object for the end time,  With these too you can get the elapsed time from the difference between initial and end time...or the timespan you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You need:

```
String.Format(@"Time : {0:mm\:ss\.ff}", ts)
```

Where `"ts"` is your `TimeSpan` object. You can also always extend this to include hours etc. The `fff` stuff is the number of significant digits of the second fractions

Comment: But the poster is asking for 100's of a second. This works, but 686 milliseconds should be rounded to 69

Comment: @user3444696 Did you read this - "The fff stuff is the number of significant digits of the second fractions". Depending on the number of 'f''s you will receive the same amount of **significant** digits from the seconds fraction.

Comment: @user3444696 sure it does - the second `f` represents hundredths. the first one is tenths.

Comment: I just edited my comment.  I saved it to quickly.  Looks like he/she wants to round to the nearest 100'th.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [custom TimeSpan format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings) for that (here we're only displaying the first two digits of the milliseconds with `ff`, which represent the hundredths):

```
ClockTextBlock.Text = ts.ToString("mm\\:ss\\:ff");
```

Comment: But the poster is asking for 100's of a second.  This works, but 686 milliseconds should be rounded to 69 hundredths.

Comment: @user3444696 Should it really? Why do you think so? I notice that you also submitted an answer that does not round up...

Comment: Good catch.  I fixed mine so that it does round.  Yours gives hundredths but it won't round.  Why do I think so?  Try this:  

TimeSpan ts = newTimeSpan(3, 2, 3, 2, 968);
string str = String.Format(@"ts : {0:mm\:ss\.ff}", ts);
Console.Writeline(str);

Comment: @user3444696 I mean why do you think the number should be rounded up rather than truncated.

Comment: Initially, I thought that was why he was using Round().  However, it also makes sense to round it because 686 ms is closer 69 100ths than 68 100ths, and 689 is even closer -- it seems more correct.

Comment: But doesn't that depend completely on what this is being used for? If, for example, this were being used in a condition that specified that some action should not take place until a specific time was reached, then rounding up will cause the action to occur prematurely. In that case, the number should represent the most recent *actual* value of the hundredths place, not the *nearest* value.

Comment: @user3444696 I'm also thinking of a stopwatch that only displays seconds, which would not round the seconds from `0` to `1` as soon as `501` milliseconds have passed.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a `DateTime` type timezone and plus with `Timespan` span.
You would get a datetime and format it!

```
  DateTime timezone = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);

  TimeSpan span = stopWatch.Elapsed;

  ClockTextBlock.Text=(timezone + span).ToString("mm:ss:ff");
```

Comment: But the poster is asking for 100's of a second. This works, but 686 milliseconds should be rounded to 69

Answer (score -1):

Since a millisecond is 1/1000 of a second, all you need to do is divide the milliseconds by 10 to get 100's of a second.  If you are concerned about rounding, then just do it manually before the division.

```
    int hundredths = (int)Math.Round((double)ts.Milliseconds / 10);

    currentTime = String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", ts.Minutes.ToString(D2), ts.Seconds.ToString(D2), hundredths.ToString(D2);

    ClockTextBlock.Text = currentTime;
```

Comment: Why do you cast an `int` to a `double`, then call `Round`, which rounds it to an integral value (which it already was) and then cast that back to an `int` again? The first line does nothing. It could be removed and the second line could just be `int hundredths = ts.Milliseconds / 10;` Did you leave out something?

Answer (score -1):

Just put the format in toString and it simply will show you the desired format :)

```
        Stopwatch s2 = new Stopwatch();
        s2.Start();
        Console.WriteLine(s2.Elapsed.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"));
```